# Grouping a set of data by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The question is a little on the noobish end as I'm just starting to mess with PHP. However my project is to create a basic statistics page. So let me go ahead and explain exactly what I'm looking for (in it's most basic form).
Basically I have an table with the following structure. `[ TransactionID, Date, Amount ]`
What I want to do is group everything by a certain date and display all of the transactions that happened on that date, so I believe the query would look something like this.

```
Select * from table where date = 2014-05-24
```

Alright, that's all fine and dandy and I can easily get the sum like that, but How would I get the transactions for a certain month, or year even?

This is a personal project and won't be used at all on a professional scale, but it's something that I'm working on as a hobby.

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? MySQL? Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Date` column is of type `DateTime`, you may see [date functions in Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year).
To get all records for a specific date like 2014-05-24 :

```
Select * from table T where Date(T.date) = Date('2014-05-24')
```

To get all records for a specific year like 2014 :

```
Select * from table T where Year(T.date) = Year('2014-05-24')
```

For a specific month of year like 5th of 2014

```
Select * from table T where Year(T.date) = Year('2014-05-24') 
and 
Month(T.date) = Month('2014-05-24')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `EXTRACT()` FUNCTION, e.g.

```
     select * from table where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `date`) = '2014'

     select * from table where EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`) = '201405'
```

[see date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways than my example bellow, but a basic way could be :

SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE columname BETWEEN '2012-12-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-25 23:59:59